# Gradle installation through docker file

Tags: docker, gradle

I wrote a docker file with gradle installations inside it. It shows Gradle version with gradle -v command  but while I am running through jenkins job with gradle -v command in execute shell while building a job [it shows as gradle:not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7emiW.png)

Please check the image mentioned
This is gradle installation in docker file

```
#Install gradle

RUN cd /usr/lib \

&& wget https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip -o   gradle-bin.zip \


&& unzip "gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip" \

&& ln -s "/usr/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle" /usr/bin/gradle \

&& rm "gradle-bin.zip"

#Env set up

ENV GRADLE_HOME=usr/lib/gradle-3.4.1

#ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

ENV PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Can you post the dockerfile in the question?

Comment: You have missed "/" in GRADLE_HOME value  usr/lib/gradle-3.4.1. It should be /usr/lib/gradle-3.4.1

Comment: I just want to note that there is a official [Gradle](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle/) docker in the repository.

Comment: The recommended way to "install" gradle is to add the gradle wrapper to the root of the project where gradle is used: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this, work for me.

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN ./gradlew build

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","./build/libs/app-0.1.0.jar"]
```